# Routes not loading after using "npm run build" in React

Tags: reactjs, build, react-router

This project works perfectly in development using "npm start" but after running "npm run build" and accessing the index.html from the build folder, it does not seem to load any of my Route components. The only thing that loads is my Header component specified in App.js as it is the only one not inside a Route. I also get an error in the console when clicking a button from header that corresponds to a Route  which says "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///C:/register' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL" file:///C:/... I might have something wrong with the paths, any suggestions?

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';
import './App.scss';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

import store from './store';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';
import Header from './components/Layout/Header';
import Landing from './components/Layout/Landing';
import ProjectBoard from './components/ProjectBoard/ProjectBoard';
import Register from './components/UserManagement/Register';
import Login from './components/UserManagement/Login';
import setJWTToken from './securityUtils/setJWTToken';
import { SET_CURRENT_USER } from './actions/types';
import { logout } from './actions/securityActions';

const jwtToken = localStorage.jwtToken;

if (jwtToken) {
    setJWTToken(jwtToken);
    const decoded_jwtToken = jwt_decode(jwtToken);
    store.dispatch({
        type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
        payload: decoded_jwtToken
    });

    const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
    if (decoded_jwtToken.exp < currentTime) {
        store.dispatch(logout());
        window.location.href = '/';
    }
}

function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Header />
                {
                    // Public Routes
                }
                <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
                <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
                <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                {
                    // Private Routes
                }
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path='/projectBoard/:id'
                        render={props => <ProjectBoard {...props} isDemo={false} />}
                    />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```js
{
    "name": "react-client",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
        "react": "^16.10.1",
        "react-beautiful-dnd": "^12.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.10.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.1.1",
        "react-scripts": "3.1.2",
        "redux": "^4.0.4",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "styled-components": "^4.4.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
    "homepage": "."
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta
            name="React Client"
            content="React Client"
        />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest" />
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5" />
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />

        <script
            src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d4e16c04e7.js"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <title>React Client</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Error in Console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading the index.html file directly from the */dist* folder fails because it expects to be accessed from a web server.

You can run a local web server by installing the npm package `http-server`

This command will install a suitable web server:
 **npm install http-server -g** This command might also require admin privileges. So if you're running on a unix/linux/osx system, run like this:
**sudo npm install http-server -g**, and enter you password when asked.

Then run the server from the root of your project by typing

**http-server ./dist**

Open your browser and visit

**http://localhost**

There are several reason running a file directly like this won't work. One reason would be webpages are not meant to load resources asynchronously directly from the file system.

Any http server should work in place of the npm module suggested. Just make sure you point it at the correct folder. In this case: *./dist*

The directions would vary based on what operating system you're running. In general it just needs to be loaded from a server. And that server can be running locally.

**EDIT**: I'm realizing now that you're running on a windows machine. If you're running the scripts from a unix like terminal emulator they should still work with little modification. An alternative command you can try using is: **npx http-server ./dist'** This will run the same server without installing it, and be less dependent on your operating system.

Comment: I didn't realize the build files needed to be served from a server and not the local file system, that cleared a lot of problems that I thought I had up. I installed the http-server package and was able to serve my build files using the  command "http-server'" in the build directory. React "npm run build" doesn't create a "dist" folder so I just needed to run the command in the build folder. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same problem, i am not function :( any solutions?

Answer (score 6):

You can change BrouserRouter into HashRouter. I have the same problem like yours and i solve the problem by doing this.

Comment: i try this but not function :(

Comment: dear Alice, your answer deserves 100 upvotes. i searched almost all the question-and-answer programming websites and i can't believe that i could finally find the right solution to this problem by reading your answer. thank you so much!
i had the same issue with `Routes` and `Switches`. the issue was due to some changes in the newer versions of React. same with `BrowserRouter` and `HashRouter`.

Comment: I do agree that this answer is so underrated , we just need this replacement and everything is working fine